# Not able to create order from backend (Magento 2.3.4)

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order

Hello i am trying to place order from backend using credit card
but it shows the following error

**i saw ajax request response after "submit order" button**
its seems ok

```
{"payflowpro":{"fields":{"result":"0","securetoken":"3C5lcEtAOj0WOS78aCfHP1gqH","securetokenid":"K4Kw7aNqhWsiuFfqp8cTiDtl0bFVYcZs","respmsg":"Approved","result_code":"0"}},"success":true,"error":false}
```

Still order does not gets created & page does not redirected

**i get this just after the clicking the "submit order button"
in system.log file"**

```
[2020-08-12 12:12:19] main.ERROR: No such entity with cartId = 0 [] []
```

any thoughts on this ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with stripe on 2.3.5-p2. Similarly the submit to stripe is successful but the next step somehow fails - the order is never created

Comment: Clear cookie & check if it works then.

Comment: stripe cookies or magento cookies?

Comment: I was deleting 'payflowpro' cookie, as it was causing issue.

Comment: You can check in the cookie tab in browser, & try clearing one cache at a time & try creating order from admin. It might work as it worked for me.

Comment: You can also take a look here - https://mage2.pro/t/topic/4252/2

Comment: I think it is that a session cookie is not being set or not coming back from the payment system